# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.util.ArrayOutOfBoundsException when converting string to int

Tags: java, android

I have a dialog fragment that contains edit text's in it. These edit texts will allow the user to enter information about an event which is eventName, eventStartDate, eventStartTime, eventEndDate and, eventEndTime.

When the 'Add' or positive button is clicked, the information for the dates and time are taken in as strings, these strings are then split so I can get the information as individual variables. These variables are then cast into int values.

Then I want these int values to be put into an SQLiteDatabase which I set up. So I pass the values into the insertRow() method.

Here is the DialogFragment class:

```
private class EventDetailsDialogFragment
{
    public Dialog onCreateDialogFragment(final Bundle savedInstanceState, Calendar time)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_event_details, null));
        builder.setTitle("Empty time clicked:\n" + String.valueOf(time.getTime()))
               .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
               {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        String name = "";
                        int startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute;
                        int endYear, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinute;

                        EditText eventName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEventName);
                        EditText eventStartDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEventStartDate);
                        EditText eventStartTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEventStartTime);
                        EditText eventEndDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEventEndDate);
                        EditText eventEndTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEventEndTime);

                        String [] startDate = String.valueOf(eventStartDate).split("/");
                        String [] startTime = String.valueOf(eventStartTime).split(":");
                        String [] endDate = String.valueOf(eventEndDate).split("/");
                        String [] endTime = String.valueOf(eventEndTime).split(":");

                        name = String.valueOf(eventName);

                        startYear = Integer.parseInt(startDate[2]);
                        startMonth = Integer.parseInt(startDate[1]);
                        startDay = Integer.parseInt(startDate[0]);
                        startHour = Integer.parseInt(startTime[0]);
                        startMinute = Integer.parseInt(startTime[1]);

                        endYear = Integer.parseInt(endDate[2]);
                        endMonth = Integer.parseInt(endDate[1]);
                        endDay = Integer.parseInt(endDate[0]);
                        endHour = Integer.parseInt(endTime[0]);
                        endMinute = Integer.parseInt(endTime[1]);


                        long newId = myDatabase.insertRow(name, startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour,
                                startMinute, endYear, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinute);
                    }
                }).setNeutralButton("Show Events", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                      {
                          Cursor cursor = myDatabase.getAllRows();
                          displayRecordSet(cursor);
                      }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).show();
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

When I'm in the application and the dialog pops up, I input information for an event. For example, (Database Systems Exam, 04/03/2015, 15:00, 04/03/2015, 17:30). Then when the add button is clicked, the application stops working.

I went into the LogCat and this is the error that it is giving me:

```
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.example.davidnkanga.sample.MainActivity$EventDetailsDialogFragment$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:174)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-23 20:03:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 174 in my main activity is:

```
startYear = Integer.parseInt(startDate[2]);
```

I've tried many ways to convert the string to int but to no avail.

Comment: String [] startDate = String.valueOf(eventStartDate).split("/");
This line needs to be fixed. Are you getting single value or list of values from 'eventStartDate'

Comment: @prudhvi I'm getting a single string, and splitting it. So for example I'll have "23/11/2015" and this is going to split it at every "/". So it startDate[] will have 23, 11, 2015.

Comment: I have figured out what's wrong with your approach. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not because you're converting `String` to `int`. Your `startDate` array has a length of 1 but you're accessing index 2 from it. So change the length of the array to a value you would be accessing in your code.

**Here is the solution**

```
EditText eventStartDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEventStartDate);
```

In the above line, `eventStartDate` refers to a `View`, not the actual String data(date in your case) inside that view. So your array `startDate` is having only one element in it.

```
String [] startDate = String.valueOf(eventStartDate).split("/");
```

Replace all the above kind of lines by the below one

```
String[] startDate = eventStartDate.getText().toString().split("/");
```

Now you'll have 3 elements in your array as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2
```

Say that you can try access on a element in the index 2 but the array only have one element (length = 1).